# How can I ingore placeholders in property file in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I have urls like localhost:8080/boot/${task}/say
in property file, I am reading this url in my code using poprerty placeholder, problem is here spring boot trying to search placeholder in url. I want to ingore that and send complete url with that placeholder into response.
I have already declared bean of PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigure and setIgoreUnresolvablePlaceholders as true but still it asking for value of placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape `$` sign.

```
localhost:8080/boot/#{'$'}{task}/say
```